# getRootInActiveWindow() always null at onAccessibilityEvent

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

in an Accessibility Services I'm dealing with a very strange situation. The getRootInActiveWindow() is always null at onAccessibilityEvent.

This is the logcat results:

- E/PackageName: com.google.android.packageinstaller E/EventName:
  TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED====null====CONTENT_CHANGE_TYPE_UNDEFINED====null====[Packageinstaller]
- **E/getRootInActiveWindow(): getRootInActiveWindow() = Null**
- E/PackageName: com.google.android.packageinstaller E/EventName:
  TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED====null====CONTENT_CHANGE_TYPE_UNDEFINED====null====[3D
  Live Wallpaper, Do you want to uninstall this app?, CANCEL, OK]
- **E/getRootInActiveWindow(): getRootInActiveWindow() = Null**

The message **getRootInActiveWindow(): getRootInActiveWindow() = Null** is generated at the begining of  findAlertDialogNode, when the app will find the "OK" button.

What am I doing wrong here? I appreciate your help.

**The code:**

**Accessibility service XML**

```
<accessibility-service
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
android:packageNames="com.google.android.packageinstaller"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
android:canPerformGestures="true"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
/>
```

**onAccessibilityEvent**

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    String eventText = getTypeName(event.getEventType()) + "===="
            + event.getContentDescription() +  "===="
            + getContentChangeTypesName(event.getContentChangeTypes())   +  "===="
            + event.getSource()  +  "===="
            + event.getText(); //TODO REMOVE
    if (event.getPackageName() != null) Log.e("PackageName", event.getPackageName().toString()); //TODO REMOVE
    Log.e("EventName", eventText); //TODO REMOVE

    PreferenceManager preferenceManager = new PreferenceManager(mContext);
    if (!preferenceManager.isCleanUpProcessStarted()) return;
    if (!preferenceManager.isScreenBlocked()) return;

    List<App> selectedAppsForDeletionList = preferenceManager.getSelectedAppsForDeletion();
    if (selectedAppsForDeletionList == null || selectedAppsForDeletionList.size() == 0) return;

    selectedAppPackageNameForDeletion = null;
    AccessibilityNodeInfo OkButton = findAlertDialogNode(getRootInActiveWindow(), selectedAppsForDeletionList);
    if (OkButton != null) {
        OkButton.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction.ACTION_CLICK.getId());
        removePackageFromDeletionList(selectedAppsForDeletionList, selectedAppPackageNameForDeletion);
        Log.e("PackageName Deleted ", selectedAppPackageNameForDeletion); //TODO REMOVE
        startSelectedAppsForDeletion();
    }
}
```

**findAlertDialogNode**

```
private AccessibilityNodeInfo findAlertDialogNode(AccessibilityNodeInfo root, List<App> selectedAppsForDeletionList) {

        String packageName = null;
        if (root == null) {
            Log.e("getRootInActiveWindow()", "getRootInActiveWindow() = Null "); //TODO REMOVE
            return null;
        }

        Deque<AccessibilityNodeInfo> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
        deque.add(root);

        while (!deque.isEmpty()) {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo node = deque.removeFirst();
            if (node == null) return null;

            if (node.getClassName().equals("android.widget.TextView")) {
                if (packageName == null)
                    packageName = findPackageToUninstall(node, selectedAppsForDeletionList);
            }

            if (node.getActionList().contains(AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction.ACTION_CLICK)) {
                if (node.getText() != null) {
                    if (node.getText().equals("OK")) {
                        if (packageName != null) {
                            //removePackageFromDeletionList(selectedAppsForDeletionList, packageName);
                            Log.e("PackageName Selected For Deletion ", packageName); //TODO REMOVE
                            selectedAppPackageNameForDeletion = packageName;
                            return node;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildCount(); i++) {
                deque.addLast(node.getChild(i));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

You need this two line in xml

```
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows|flagIncludeNotImportantViews"

android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
```

It works on me, just in case, this is my xml:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows|flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="false"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="@string/user_permission_accessibility_description"
    android:notificationTimeout="1000" />
```